# Is it worth removing upgrades before selling unwanted items?

Tags: dragon-age-inquisition

So I have been upgrading the gear on my party members today and I notice that upgrades are actual items which you craft and then place into a piece of gear.

When I find better gear is it worth going back to Haven, taking out the upgrades, marking the old gear as 'Valuables' and then putting the upgrades back into the new gear?

Just some context, I'm using all tier 1 gear and upgrades at the moment.

Will I get more gold for the item if I sell it with upgrades still in it? Or should I be hoarding upgrades?

Comment: I found that hording the upgrades meant getting rather close to the inventory limit. So I would evaluate each upgrade and certainly sell those that you're unlikely to need.

Comment: Yeah, I've already taken the inventory bonus perk ;)

Comment: I started to sell upgrades even with multiple inventory upgrades. I'm not sure if keeping them is a good idea, but I started to sell all the common upgrades I didn't use at some point to get some room in my inventory.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think anyone is answering whether or not having the upgrade present causes vendors to buy it for more or not. I'll try to investigate that.

Answer (score 2):

I have just tested this and the price of the item is unaffected by the upgrades, so you can make more money by removing the upgrades and then selling them separately.